# Mongoose error when testing Babel-node Express App using Jest

Tags: node.js, mongoose, jestjs, supertest

This is my Jest configuration:

```
  "jest": {
    "testEnvironment": "node",
    "coveragePathIgnorePatterns": [
      "/node_modules/"
    ]
  },
```

This is my test:

```js
import request from 'supertest';
import { myapp } from '../src/index';

describe('Post Endpoints', () => {
  it('should run api root', async () => {
    const res = await request(myapp).get('/api/v1');
    expect(res.statusCode).toEqual(200);
    expect(res.body).toHaveProperty('version');
  });
});
```

This is my http server (express app) last lines, which listening on 3000 in test environment:

```js
...
import './mongodb';
...
if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') server.listen(800 + process.env.NODE_APP_INSTANCE);
else if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'test') server.listen(300 + process.env.NODE_APP_INSTANCE);
else server.listen(80, () => logger.info(' Single core development server started on 80.'));

export { server, myApp };
```

And this is my mongoose file:

```js
import mongoose, { mongo } from 'mongoose';
import { mongodbURL, mongodbURLdev, mongodbURLdevRemote, mongodbURLtest, debugMode } from '../config/config.json';
import logger from '../lib/logger';

mongoose.Promise = global.Promise;
let env = process.env.NODE_ENV;

mongoose.set(`debug`, debugMode || env === 'production' ? false : true);

let dbURL =
  env === 'production'
    ? mongodbURL
    : env === 'development'
    ? mongodbURLdev
    : env === 'developmentRemote'
    ? mongodbURLdevRemote
    : mongodbURLtest;
try {
  mongoose.connect(dbURL, {
    useNewUrlParser: true,
    useCreateIndex: true,
    useUnifiedTopology: true
  });
} catch (e) {
  mongoose.createConnection(dbURL, { useNewUrlParser: true, useCreateIndex: true, useUnifiedTopology: true });
}

mongoose.connection
  .once('open', () => env !== 'production' && logger.info(`MongoDB is running in ${env} mode.`))
  .on('error', e => {
    logger.error('error on connect to mongo db.');
  });
```

But when i run `cross-env NODE_ENV=test NODE_APP_INSTANCE=0 jest --testTimeout=10000`

The router test passes but mongoose will error:

```
/node_modules/mongoose/lib/utils.js:422
        throw err;
        ^
TypeError: clone is not a function
    at format (/node_modules/mongoose/lib/drivers/node-mongodb-native/collection.js:287:11)
    at NativeCollection.$format (/node_modules/mongoose/lib/drivers/node-mongodb-native/collection.js:253:10)
```

Answer (score 0):

I found if mongoose debug mode being enable this error wil happen.